# Найти в последовательности чисел максимальную по длине цепочку из неповторяющихся нечетных чисел C++

Tags: c++, сортировка, числовые-последовательности

Как можно написать эту программу с помощью сортировки вставкой по возрастанию?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void Sort(int *mas, int n) //сортировка вставками
{int k,t;
for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
{
k=i+1;
t=mas[k];
for (int j=i+1; j>0; j--)
{
if (t<mas[j-1])
{
mas[j]=mas[j-1];
k=j-1;
}
}
mas[k]=t;
}
cout<<endl<<"массив после сортировки: ";
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
cout<<mas[i]<<"\t";
cout<<"\n";
}

int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
int n,t=0,tmax=0;
cout<<"Количество элементов в массиве "; 
cin>>n;
cout<<"\n";
int *mas=new int[n];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  *(mas+i)=rand() % 100;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  cout<<*(mas+i)<<"\t";
Sort(mas, n);
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  if(*(mas+i)%2==1)
    t++;
  else{ if(t>tmax)tmax=t;t=0;}

cout<<tmax<<" -Количество подряд идущих элементов";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: А если вы ее отсортируете, изменится же порядок? Скажем, у вас было 5 7 2 13 15 11 - и самая длинна цепочка 13 15 11. Сортируем в 2 5 7 11 13 15, и цепочка 5 7 11 13 15 - уже из пяти элементов. Сортировка же все портит?

Comment: Дали такое задание

Comment: Так вам наверное надо сортировать только текущую найденную под последовательность, а не весь массив.